# Area between $\sin x$ and $\sin 2x$ that equal

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Let $A$ be the area of region $R$ bounded by $y = \sin(x)$ and $y = \sin(2x)$ over $[0,\pi]$. Then in the interval [$\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\pi$], is there a unique (emphasis on the uniqueness) number $x$ such that the area over [$0$, $\frac{\pi}{3}$] and [$\frac{\pi}{3}$,x] have the same area? I'm leaning towards a graphical solution here: $\frac{\pi}{3}$ is the place where sinx and sin2x intersect. To make the areas equal each other, I would have to make $\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\sin(2x) - \sin(x)\mathrm{d}x + \int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{x}\sin(x) - \sin(2x)\mathrm{d}x=0$, which then I would solve for x and find the value. But is there a unique value of x? If so, what is it?

Comment: please make the integration variable and the boundary value variable different :) Afterwards, you should just solve it by directly integrating

Comment: Don't you want an equal-sign between the integrals (or a difference of integrals equaling zero) for what you are asking?  By swapping the terms in the second integral, you make both integral values positive ("area between two curves").

Comment: @BenjaminWang thanks. My main concern is whether this has a unique solution though. Looking at the graph, it seems to be unique, any proofs?

Comment: @boojum yeah, that's what should be used to solve it.

Comment: If you write the anti-derivative for $ \ \sin(2x) \ - \ \sin x \ $ and solve the trigonometric equation for where it equals zero, you will find a "trivial" solution of $ \ 0 \ $ and only one other solution in the specified interval. (There is a helpful trig identity you should use...)